Mapper class between API and DB field properties
I would like to implement a kind of mapper between db data and some other data like obtained from the response of API.
The expected behavior is following:
class IData:
    a: str = ('db_a', 'type_a')
    b: str = ('db_b', 'type_b')
    c: str = ('db_c', 'type_c')

class MyData(IData):
    a = 'api_a'
    b = 'api_b'
    c = 'api_c'

m = MyData()  # or `m = MyData`

m.a.db_name -> 'db_a'
m.a.db_type -> 'db_b'
m.a.api_name -> 'db_c'

m.get_db_names() -> ['db_a', 'db_b', 'db_c']
m.get_db_types() -> ['type_a', 'type_b', 'type_c']
m.get_api_names() -> ['api_a', 'api_b', 'api_c']  # or Nones if some are not assigned in MyData definition

I implemented it like following:
class _Field:
    def __init__(self, db_name, db_type, api_name=None):
        self.db_name = db_name
        self.db_type = db_type
        self.api_name = api_name

class _base:
    def get_db_names(self):
        return [self.__dict__[i].db_name for i in self.__dict__ if not i.startswith("_")]
    def get_db_types(self):
        return [self.__dict__[i].db_type for i in self.__dict__ if not i.startswith("_")]
    def get_api_names(self):
        return [self.__dict__[i].api_name for i in self.__dict__ if not i.startswith("_")]

class IData(_base):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = _Field("db_a", "type_a")
        self.b = _Field("db_b", "type_b")
        self.c = _Field("db_c", "type_c")

class MyData(IData):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.a.api_name = "api_a"
        self.b.api_name = "api_b"
        self.c.api_name = "api_c"

Is there some better, simpler, more robust solution using dataclasses or types (namespaces) or something else?
Also would be nice to rise an exception if for some attribute the api_name is not set in class MyData(IData) when the user is instantiating m = MyData()

Are u familiar with SQLAlchemy? It is around for 18 years and perfect for your usecase

@JoostDöbken I'm familiar but haven't used, but I used Django ORM. And I don't understand how to do it there. Could you provide some code?

So you are trying to reinvent an ORM?

Guys, if it is so simple, just feel free to provide a code for exactly my case.

you could use named tuples this maybe simplifies things.
from collections import namedtuple

DataBase = namedtuple('DataBase', ['db_name','db_type', 'api_name'], defaults=(None,))


class DataBases:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = DataBase('db_a', 'type_a', "api_a")
        self.b = DataBase('db_b', 'type_b', "api_b")
        self.c = DataBase('db_c', 'type_c', "api_c")

    def get_db_names(self):
        return [c.db_name for c in self.__dict__.values() if isinstance(c, DataBase)]
    
    def get_db_types(self):
        return [c.db_type for c in self.__dict__.values() if isinstance(c, DataBase)]
    
    def get_api_namess(self):
        return [c.api_name for c in self.__dict__.values() if isinstance(c, DataBase)]

m = MyData()
print(m.a.db_name)  # Output: db_a
print(m.get_db_names())  # Output: ['db_a', 'db_b', 'db_c']

Not sure if this is what you are looking for

One possible solution that could meet the requirements is to use a dataclass and a custom descriptor, which handles the desired behavior of the class. Here you see the code for this alternative.
class FieldDescriptor:
    def __init__(self, db_name: str, db_type: str):
        self.db_name = db_name
        self.db_type = db_type
        self.api_name = None

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return obj.__dict__.get(self.name, self)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if not isinstance(value, str):
            raise ValueError(f"API name for {self.name} must be a string")
        self.api_name = value
        obj.__dict__[self.name] = self

@dataclass
class IData:
    _fields: ClassVar[Dict[str, FieldDescriptor]] = {}

    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        cls._fields = {name: value for name, value in cls.__dict__.items() if isinstance(value, FieldDescriptor)}

    @classmethod
    def get_db_names(cls) -> List[str]:
        return [field.db_name for field in cls._fields.values()]

    @classmethod
    def get_db_types(cls) -> List[str]:
        return [field.db_type for field in cls._fields.values()]

    def get_api_names(self) -> List[str]:
        return [getattr(self, name).api_name for name in self._fields]

    def __post_init__(self):
        for name, field in self._fields.items():
            if field.api_name is None:
                raise ValueError(f"API name for {name} is not set")

class MyData(IData):
    a: FieldDescriptor = FieldDescriptor("db_a", "type_a")
    b: FieldDescriptor = FieldDescriptor("db_b", "type_b")
    c: FieldDescriptor = FieldDescriptor("db_c", "type_c")

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "api_a"
        self.b = "api_b"
        self.c = "api_c"
        super().__post_init__()

# Usage
m = MyData()

print(m.a.db_name)  # Output: db_a
print(m.a.db_type)  # Output: type_a
print(m.a.api_name)  # Output: api_a

print(MyData.get_db_names())  # Output: ['db_a', 'db_b', 'db_c']
print(MyData.get_db_types())  # Output: ['type_a', 'type_b', 'type_c']
print(m.get_api_names())  # Output: ['api_a', 'api_b', 'api_c']

# This will raise a ValueError if any api_name is not set
m_incomplete = MyData()
m_incomplete.a = "api_a"
m_incomplete.b = "api_b"
# Uncommenting the next line will raise a ValueError
# m_incomplete.__post_init__()

This code adopts dataclasses and a custom descriptor in order to achieve the desired behavior. Here's a breakdown of its key components:

FieldDescriptor: A custom descriptor class that encapsulates all the db_name, db_type, and api_name of each field.

IData: A base dataclass that contains common methods and class methods.

MyData: A FormData instance that adds the specific fields and their API names.



I think this solution is not less complex than mine.. But thank you, I found some interesting ideas
